# Cursor does not move when using arrows on gnome terminal prompt

Tags: zsh, prezto

I am on Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04 with zsh / prezto.

When moving the left / right arrow keys on terminal prompt text line, the cursor doe snot follow the movement. it does finally go to the location after you stop pressing arrow keys. Is there some time delay between the response of cursor to arrow keys.

Same problem does not occur on bash shell.